# Python if statement with string as condition

Tags: python, virtualenv

There's some code in `virtualenv` that's tripping me up. It's this:

`path.decode("utf-8") if "__DECODE_PATH__" else path`

from [activate_this.py](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/aa81cc4ade0336743f79f2b7c22b83cfc1f23f81/src/virtualenv/activation/python/activate_this.py) line 28.

How can `if "__DECODE_PATH__"` ever be false? It's possible it's a bug, but since it's in `virtualenv` and since `activate_this.py` is the means of activating `virtualenv` in the current interpreter, it's seems unlikely.

Also there is an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1993) where someone mentions having this problem but it then being resolved. No one mentions `if "__DECODE_PATH__"` looking incorrect.

Ultimately it means I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` when I try to use `activate_this.py`. However if I could convince the code to go down the `else` path it would work fine.

Note: using Python 3.8.10 in Linux Mint 20.3

Comment: I’d guess there’s some sort of preprocessor involved which replaces this string with some value or an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, it appears that file is just a template which contains some magic strings that are replaced.  In other words, they are just template variables.

You can see the replacement in action in the [`ViaTemplateActivator`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/9569493453a39d63064ed7c20653987ba15c99e5/src/virtualenv/activation/via_template.py) base class.

Then in the [`PythonActivator`](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/9569493453a39d63064ed7c20653987ba15c99e5/src/virtualenv/activation/python/__init__.py) class you can see that `"__DECODE_PATH__"` is one of those magic strings.

Comment: Thank you @Iguananaut (and @deceze). I can see now when you create a virtual env the generated `activate_this.py` has `site.addsitedir(path.decode("utf-8") if "" else path)` for me, and could have `if "yes"` on Windows.